# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.x.x.Helper.SharedPref.GetInt(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, onesignal

i'm trying to count a notification from OneSignal, and make it display in the badge, but i still getting this error. What's wrong with my code?

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NetworkBroadcastListener.iNetStats, iNotif {

Context context;
SharedPref spref;
TextView notif_badge;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

notif_badge = findViewById(R.id.cart_badge);
        setupBadge();



private void setupBadge() {
        int counter = spref.GetInt(localPref.TOTALNOTIF);
        context=this;
        spref = new SharedPref(this);
        notif_badge.setText(String.valueOf(Math.min(counter,99)));
    }
```

Here is my OneSignal ReceiveHandler

```
public class NotifReceivedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler {

    Context context;

    SharedPref spref;

    public NotifReceivedHandler(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        spref = new SharedPref(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.x.x.NOTIFICATION");
        intent.putExtra("body",notification.payload.body);
        intent.putExtra("title",notification.payload.title);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
        spref.AddInt(localPref.TOTALNOTIF,spref.GetInt(localPref.TOTALNOTIF)+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SharedPref` object is **null**, do like this way:

```
private void setupBadge() {
    spref = new SharedPref(this); // This line initializes spref object.
    int counter = spref.GetInt(localPref.TOTALNOTIF); // here, spref was null because, it wasn't initialized yet.
    context=this;
    notif_badge.setText(String.valueOf(Math.min(counter,99)));
}
```

Comment: hey thank you it's working, but when i opened the notification. it should be dissapeared or reduced, how to do this? i'm new with this. appreciated

Comment: You'll need to decrease your counter from shared preference once your notification opened, also don't forget to update the UI.

Comment: spref.AddInt(localPref.DECNOTIF,spref.GetInt(localPref.TOTALNOTIF)-1); is this right?

Comment: No, save your decremented counter on same variable like this : `spref.AddInt(localPref.TOTALNOTIF, spref.GetInt(localPref.TOTALNOTIF) - 1);`

Comment: So how i implement a method in my Activity? if the shared preference variable is same?

Comment: It's unclear from the question, and there's no lot of code in it which makes me understand your requirement. consider asking another question or share some code with updated question about what you want to achieve.